# tablesaw library: join tables with different column type

Tags: tablesaw

I need to use dataframe library to join the results of two different queries, or query result with the JSON result. I did some research and found the tablesaw library. During the implementation, I faced some problems.

Does anyone have experience with this library?

How can I join tables with different columns type?

For example, the first table column is an integer type and the second table column is a long type, and I want to join tables with those columns. Now I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: tech.tablesaw.index.FloatIndex cannot be cast to tech.tablesaw.index.IntIndex
```

Comment: Hi, I have two tables with a common attribute id. how can I join these two tables?

Comment: Table tb1= Table.read().db(resultSet1, "t1");
Table tb2= Table.read().db(resultSet2, "t2");

Table result = tb1.joinOn("columnname").inner(tb2, true, "columnname");